# MEAN - Node - Mongoose - Error

Tags: mongodb, mean

trying create simple API using MEAN.

am following below youtube link as guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMOIr_VwwAk

setting port on 3000. when try to run it, throws error like as fallows

```
**mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/restful');
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined**
```

server.js

```
 var express = require ('express'),
    restful = require('node-rest-client'),
    mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var app = express();
app.get(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/restful');

var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    sku: String,
    price:Number
});

var Products =restful.model('products',ProductSchema);
Products.methods(['get','put','post','delete']);
Products.register(app,'/api/products');
app.listen(3000);
console.log("am running on port 3000");
```

package.json

```
   {
  "name": "restful",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mangoose": "latest",
    "node-restful": "latest"
  }
}
```

this what have start with as of now.

helps much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your **package.json** appears to have typos.  Did you get errors when you ran `npm install`?

I assume **mangoose** is meant to be **mongoose**.
Also **node-restful** does not match any of your require statements.  Instead you have `restful = require('node-rest-client')`

Comment: didn't get no errors while installing package . what code would be alternate instead of 'node-rest client'

Comment: It depends on which package you are trying to use.  If you want to use **node-restful**, then you'd change your require statement to `restful = require('node-rest-client')`.  If you want to use **node-rest-client**, you'd change your install dependencies to include `"node-rest-client": "latest"`

Comment: well, thanks @wake .  now the error has shown like below                                              
 Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined eventhough i have install latest dependencies of Mongoose .. i did changed as you like this {
  "name": "restful",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mangoose": "latest",
    "node-rest-client": "latest"
  }
}